# Move radial tick labels on a polar plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, polar-coordinates

From [matplotlib examples](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/polar_demo.html):

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sbs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

r = np.arange(0, 3.0, 0.01)
theta = 2 * np.pi * r

ax = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)
ax.plot(theta, r, color='r', linewidth=3)
ax.set_rmax(2.0)
ax.grid(True)

ax.set_title("A line plot on a polar axis", va='bottom')
plt.show()
```

[image: polar plot]

How to move the radial tick labels (0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0) to a different angle, say 120 deg?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

With version 1.4 or later, you can use "set_rlabel_position".  e.g. to place the radial ticks a long a line at, say, 135 degrees:

```
ax.set_rlabel_position(135)
```

The relevant documentation is residing [here](http://matplotlib.org/devel/add_new_projection.html#matplotlib.projections.polar.PolarAxes.set_rlabel_position), a bit hidden under "projections".

Adding the line above yields (I don't have seaborn so this has default matplotlib formatting):

[image: polar axis example ticks at 135 degrees]

Prior to 1.4, `ax.set_rgrids` can take an angle argument.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to run the example-code with the edit from @alkamid's answer, but eventually ended with an error

```
AttributeError: 'PolarAxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'set_rlabel_position'
```

My matplotlib version is 1.3.1. However I found this answer [python matplolib polar chart x-axis label position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21780083/python-matplolib-polar-chart-x-axis-label-position) with the following line of code:

```
ax.set_rgrids([5,10], angle=22)
```

This worked for me and produced the wanted output.