# Setting the style of the center marker in a matplotlib polar plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I asked a related question in [Adding tick marks on Thetagrid lines of a polar plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50704932/adding-tick-marks-on-thetagrid-lines-of-a-polar-plot?answertab=active#tab-top) and was able to answer most of that question. However, I can't find a way to style the center marker. This marker is always the color and style of the marker below the last theta grid label (TG06 in the example plot). I've noted this in a comment inside of the decorate_ticks function. How do I style the center marker differently than the marker below the last theta grid label?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Radar(object):

  def __init__(self, fig, titles, label, rect=None):
    if rect is None:
        rect = [0.05, 0.15, 0.95, 0.75]

    self.n = len(titles)
    self.angles = [a if a <=360. else a - 360. for a in np.arange(90, 90+360, 360.0/self.n)]
    self.axes = [fig.add_axes(rect, projection="polar", label="axes%d" % i) 
                    for i in range(self.n)]

    self.ax = self.axes[0]

    # Show the labels
    self.ax.set_thetagrids(self.angles, labels=titles, fontsize=14, weight="bold", color="black")

    for ax in self.axes[1:]:
        ax.patch.set_visible(False)
        ax.grid(False)
        ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)
        self.ax.yaxis.grid(False)

    for ax, angle in zip(self.axes, self.angles):
        ax.set_rgrids(range(1, 6), labels=label, angle=angle, fontsize=12)
        # hide outer spine (circle)
        ax.spines["polar"].set_visible(False)
        ax.set_ylim(0, 6)
        ax.xaxis.grid(True, color='black', linestyle='-', zorder=1)

        # draw a line on the y axis at each label
        ax.tick_params(axis='y', pad=0, left=True, length=6, width=1, direction='inout')

  def decorate_ticks(self, axes):
    for idx, tick in enumerate(axes.xaxis.majorTicks):
        # get the gridline
        gl = tick.gridline
        gl.set_marker('o')
        gl.set_markersize(15)
        if idx == 0:
            gl.set_markerfacecolor('#003399')
        elif idx == 1:
            gl.set_markerfacecolor('#336666')
        elif idx == 2:
            gl.set_markerfacecolor('#336699')
        elif idx == 3:
            gl.set_markerfacecolor('#CC3333')
        elif idx == 4:
            gl.set_markerfacecolor('#CC9933')
        # this doesn't get used. The center doesn't seem to be different than 5
        else:
            gl.set_markerfacecolor('#000000')

        if idx == 0 or idx == 3:
            tick.set_pad(10)
        else:
            tick.set_pad(30)

  def plot(self, values, *args, **kw):
    angle = np.deg2rad(np.r_[self.angles, self.angles[0]])
    values = np.r_[values, values[0]]
    self.ax.plot(angle, values, *args, **kw)

fig = plt.figure(1)

titles = ['TG01', 'TG02', 'TG03', 'TG04', 'TG05', 'TG06']
label = list("ABCDE")

radar = Radar(fig, titles, label)
radar.plot([3.75, 3.25, 3.0, 2.75, 4.25, 3.5], "-", linewidth=2, color="b",   alpha=.7, label="Data01")
radar.plot([3.25, 2.25, 2.25, 2.25, 1.5, 1.75],"-", linewidth=2, color="r", alpha=.7, label="Data02")

radar.decorate_ticks(radar.ax)

# this avoids clipping the markers below the thetagrid labels
radar.ax.xaxis.grid(clip_on = False)

radar.ax.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.10),
  fancybox=True, shadow=True, ncol=4)

plt.show()
```

current rendering showing the last marker black below the last theta grid label and also in the center (last applied marker color):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `gl` objects are really just `Line2D` objects on the matplotlib axes. Each one has a point at (0,0) and a point at (0,1). The second point is the one you see each colour for. The first, at (0,0), is the one at the centre. You only see the last one, because it gets covered up by each subsequent colour.

One simple solution would be to simply plot a point at the centre with the colour you want. For example, add this line at the end of `decorate_ticks`, after the `for idx, tick` loop:

```
axes.plot(0, 0, 'o', markersize=15, markerfacecolor='m', markeredgecolor='k')
```

Which gives the following plot:

[image]

For completeness, here's the whole function:

```
def decorate_ticks(self, axes):
    for idx, tick in enumerate(axes.xaxis.majorTicks):
        # get the gridline
        gl = tick.gridline
        gl.set_marker('o')
        gl.set_markersize(15)
        if idx == 0:
            gl.set_markerfacecolor('#003399')
        elif idx == 1:
            gl.set_markerfacecolor('#336666')
        elif idx == 2:
            gl.set_markerfacecolor('#336699')
        elif idx == 3:
            gl.set_markerfacecolor('#CC3333')
        elif idx == 4:
            gl.set_markerfacecolor('#CC9933')
        # this doesn't get used. The center doesn't seem to be different than 5
        else:
            gl.set_markerfacecolor('#000000')

        if idx == 0 or idx == 3:
            tick.set_pad(10)
        else:
            tick.set_pad(30)
    axes.plot(0, 0, 'o', markersize=15, markerfacecolor='m', markeredgecolor='k')
```